# Contador de vistas en una intranet

Tags: php, contador

** Buenos días, actualmente estoy creando una pagina web para ser vista en una intranet, la cual no deja que instalemos algún programa a menos de que se otorguen los permisos y bloquea algunos sitios web si se intenta acceder a ellos.

Comento esto porque se me solicita agregar un contador de visitas a la pagina, pero con lo antes mencionado, no es posible instalar un servidor local ni algún otro programa para una base de datos.

Me piden que, por así decirlo, la base de datos donde se guarde el conteo sea en un archivo .txt y que se reinicie el conteo cada mes.

¿Existe una manera de crear un contador de vistas que respete las características que ya he mencionado?

Había consultado en internet y encontré un vídeo donde la persona que imparte el tutorial, lo crea con php y su base de datos es en un archivo .txt, pero tengo entendido que para que esto funcione correctamente, debe de estar instalado algún servidor local y, como ya lo mencione, no me es posible hacer eso.

dejo el código en php que mencione:

> ```
> <?php
> function contador()
> {
>     $archivo = "contador.txt"; //el archivo que contiene en numero
>     $f = fopen($archivo, "r"); //abrimos el archivo en modo de lectura
>     if($f)
>     {
>         $contador = fread($f, filesize($archivo)); //leemos el archivo
>         $contador = $contador + 1; //sumamos +1 al contador
>         fclose($f);
>     }
>     $f = fopen($archivo, "w+");
>     if($f)
>     {
>         fwrite($f, $contador);
>         fclose($f);
>     }
>     return $contador;
> } ?>
> ```

Me comentaron que seria mejor hacerlo con un xhtml, pero no tengo ni idea sobre ese tema.
les agradezco de ante mano si pueden ayudarme con esto **

Comment: he editado la pregunta y colocado el código que mencionaba, gracias nwn